# What stories are set in George R.R. Martin's 'future history' universe? (the setting for Dying of the Light)

Tags: setting, the-thousand-worlds

Dreamsongs vol 1 lists the following in the intro to Section 3:

- The Hero (mentioned)
- Dying of the Light (first novel, mentioned)
- Included in Dreamsongs Vol 1

  - A Song for Lya
  - This Tower of Ashes
  - And Sever Times Never Kill Man
  - The Stone City
  - Bitterblooms
  - The Way of Cross and Dragon

What other stories are set in this setting?

Comment: Excellent! I'd read the Dying of the light years ago but had no idea it was part of a series. Thanks :)

Comment: Understandable because of the success of GoT, but I wish he would write more SF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This series was a hard one to try to track down, but it became easier once I found that the series' name is "The Thousand Worlds." Here's what I was able to find:

- "A Song for Lya"
- "And Seven Times Never Kill Man"
- "Bitterblooms"
- "Dark, Dark Were the Tunnels"
- "In the House of the Worm"
- "Men of Greywater Station"
- "Nightflyers"
- "Sandkings"
- "Starlady"
- "The Glass Flower"
- "The Hero"
- "The Stone City"
- "This Tower of Ashes"
- "Warship" (with with George Guthridge)
- "With Morning Comes Mistfall"
- Haviland Tuf stories (collected in *Tuf Voyaging*):

  - "The Plague Star"
  - "A Beast for Norn"
  - "Guardians"
  - "Call Him Moses"
  - "Loaves and Fishes"
  - "Manna from Heaven"
  - "Second Helpings"

There's also a never-finished novel, *Avalon*.

– [Source for most of this](http://www.tor.com/blogs/2010/03/honour-to-your-holdfast-honour-to-your-teyn-george-rr-martins-lemgdying-of-the-lightlemg#96913)

Comment: I loved Sandkings. I never knew it was part of a unified future universe along with Haviland Tuf. I love Tuf's cats.

Comment: Fun fact: Sandkings was adapted into an episode of The Outer Limits (written by Martin's frequent collaborator Melinda M. Snodgrass): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sandkings  This was my favourite episode of the series, and at the time I had no idea it was based on George R. R. Martin's work!

Answer (score 6):

This is what I found regarding the Thousand Worlds

- "A Song for Lya" (Mentions Hrangans)
- "And Seven Times Never Kill Man" (Mentions Hrangans, Fyndii, the Pale Child)
- "Bitterblooms" (Mentions Avalon)
- "Dying of the Light" (Mentions Hrangans, Fyndii, Avalon, Earth Ecological Corps, Celia, Jamison's World)
- "In the House of the Worm" (Earth's Ecological Corps appears)
- "Men of Greywater Station" (Mentions Fyndii)
- "Nightflyers"(Mentions Hrangans)
- "Sandkings"(Mentions Celia's World)
- "Starlady" (Mentions Hrangans)
- "The Glass Flower"(Mentions Fyndii, Liars)
- "The Hero" (Mentions Hrangans)
- "The Lonely Songs of Laren Dorr" (Mentions the Pale Child)
- "The Stone City" (Mentions Hrangans, Fyndii)
- "The Way of Cross and Dragon" (Mentions Celia's World, Liars)
- "This Tower of Ashes" (Mentions Jamison's World)

-"Tuf Voyaging" (Mentions Earth Ecological Corps, Hrangans)

-- "The Plague Star"
-- "A Beast for Norn"
-- "Guardians"
-- "Call Him Moses"
-- "Loaves and Fishes"
-- "Manna from Heaven"
-- "Second Helpings"

- Avalon (unfinished)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I found. The last two I'm unsure about because I haven't read them yet. I'd recommend starting with The Hero, skipping Men of Greywater Station and then reading Tuf Voyaging, Sandkings and Dying Of the Light. They're all good stories.

1. The Hero
2. Men of Greywater Station
3. Bitterblooms
4. In the House of the Worm
         Tuf Voyaging
          Prologue
5. The Plague Star
6. Loaves and Fishes
7. Guardians
8. Second Helpings
9. A Beast For Norn
10. Call Him Moses
11. Manna From Heaven
12. Starlady
13. Nightflyers (Original)

    - 13b. Nightflyers (Novella)
14. This Tower of Ashes
15. And Seven Times Never Kill Man!
16. The Way of Cross and Dragon
17. Dying of the Light
18. The Glass Flower
19. The Stone City 
    The Corpse Handlers
20. Nobody Leaves New Pittsburg
21. Override
22. Meathouse Man
23. Sandkings
24. A Song for Lya
25. Warship
26. The Runners

Comment: I've made some edits to what I think you were going for with the markdown... feel free to roll them back if you want though.