# Does A Song of Ice and Fire take place in The Thousand Worlds?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, the-thousand-worlds

Before writing *A Song of Ice and Fire*, George R. R. Martin had written a series of science fiction stories that ended up all taking place in the same universe later titled *The Thousand Worlds*.

Do the *A Song of Ice and Fire* stories take place in the same universe? Has George ever commented on this himself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

George R. R. Martin was asked this on his "Not A Blog" and has stated that the stories are not a part of *The Thousand Worlds*. The original question/comment is quite long but see the link if you want some more context.

> Asimov and Heinlein, late in life, both seemed to feel the urge to merge all of their books and stories into one huge continuity.
>   So far I do not feel the urge. **No, Westeros is not one of the Thousand Worlds.**
>   <sub>[Not A Blog, Last Year (Writing, Editing, Producing)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610191802/https://grrm.livejournal.com/464984.html?thread=23461208)</sub>

Comment: Which is a foolish statement from a financial point of view. If he said that the Thousand Worlds books _were_ in the same universe, they would all get glossy new reprints and sell millions of copies.

Comment: @MikeScott Most of the Thousand Worlds books are out of print now and Thousand Worlds was only applied to the series after the fact from what I can see.

Comment: You're making my point for me. They wouldn't be out of print if the publishers could splash "From the universe of Game of Thrones" across the cover of new editions.

Comment: @MikeScott I know what you mean but my point was that it looks like GRRM has no interest in the series anymore. Also he's making more than enough out of ASOIAF/GoT.

Comment: Yes, GRRM has so little interest in the Thousand Worlds series that he has posed _today_ on his “Not a Blog” about a TV series and new edition of _Nightflyers_, which is set in that universe.

Comment: @MikeScott Shows how much I know :)

Comment: The Thousand and First World.