# Is there evidence for "With Morning Comes Mistfall" being part of the "Thousand Worlds" universe?

Tags: the-thousand-worlds

I just finished reading through almost all of the stories in George R. R. Martin's *The Thousand Worlds* universe. These stories are not advertised as being part of the same universe, so one has to rely on hearsay, or the author's word in order to locate them. Other than that, the only way to tell is to read them and look for clues in the text.

Wikipedia says that the story [*With Morning Comes Mistfall*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/With_Morning_Comes_Mistfall) takes place in this universe as well. The problem is that Wikipedia cites [a blog post by the author](http://www.georgerrmartin.com/oldies-but-goodies/) in which he makes no such claims (or any mention to that particular story whatsoever).

Additionally, the actual text of the story didn't ring any bells to me — it has no reference to any *The Thousand Worlds*-specific alien races or locations that I recognized. I figure if it does take place in this world, it's very early, before the major events that shaped the universe (such as the Double War).

Is there any evidence that this story does in fact take place in that universe?

Comment: Every article I can find links to the same sources you link which, like you said, make no such claim. The only thing I have found is that it was published in "Dream Songs" and every other story in there seems to be from the Thousand Worlds universe.

Comment: [related question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/866/what-stories-are-set-in-george-r-r-martins-future-history-universe-the-set/911#911) - Note that the second answer that cites specific connections omits "With Morning".

Comment: @JohnP the accepted answer to your suggested duplicate lists "Mistfall" in the series, but provides no evidence. I would not consider this a duplicate.

Comment: I just read through the story, and although I found no evidence "for" it being in the Thousand Worlds, I also found no evidence against it.

Comment: @JohnP Indeed, Preston Jacobs doesn't include Mistfall in his list (or his Thousand Worlds book club on YouTube, which is how I discovered this universe to begin with). I've edited my question title to indicate that I'm looking for evidence (like Jacobs does with the other stories).

Comment: @OrganicMarble True, but I suppose my null hypothesis is that it isn't. The other stories make specific references to Hrangans, Fyndii, Damoosh, Avalon, Prometheus, Old Poseidon, Jamison's World, Tempter's Veil, Bakkalon, etc. This one didn't, so I was curious how people (on Wikipedia and elsewhere) figured that it was.

Comment: Not a duplicate as it doesn't provide any evidence for the answer.